# leaflet setView zoom level to non integer (decimal) value in R?

Tags: r, leaflet

Using the [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) R package, is there a way to set `zoom` to a non-integer (i.e. decimal) value?

That is, something inbetween these two zoom levels:

[image]

#### Example

As `zoom` moves from level 3 through to 4, it appears as though it's being rounded to the nearest integer

The only thing changing below is the `zoom` parameter

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 3) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") 


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 3.2) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") 

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 3.4) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") 

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 3.6) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") 


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 3.8) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R") 


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom = 4) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
```

#### Question

Is there a way to set a non-integer (decimal) zoom?

Note `?setView` leads to [zoom pan options](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.1.html#zoom/pan-options), which returns a 404

Answer (score 2):

You need Fractional Zoom:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomSnap: 0.25});
```

There is more about it here:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/

I use it on one of my maps like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {attributionControl: false, crs: L.CRS.Simple, zoomSnap: 0.25, minZoom: -3});
```

...

```
map.setView(xy(<%= @image.width.to_i/2 %>, <%= @image.height.to_i/2 %>), -1.5);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like you use javascript + ruby, - it's great to know the underlying javascript / leaflet library isn't a limitation! I just need to figure out how to do it in R..

Comment: I searched the [R leaflet manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet/leaflet.pdf) but no mention of fractional zoom. Could it go by any other term?

Comment: Click on that link https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/ and search for Fractional Zoom

Comment: I use leaflet and Rails together, there is a good example of it here: https://github.com/jeremygradisher/mapping-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862639/setting-the-zoom-level-to-7-25-in-shiny-leaflet-r) you can use `zoomSnap` inside `leafletOptions`. For example:

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25)) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=-82.706838, lat=40.358615, zoom=7.25)
```

`zoomSnap` allows you to define how small the zoom level can go.