# How to customize zoom level in leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, zooming

I created a leaflet map. With `zoom=2`, I have a fairly small map, but if I zoom in at 3, the map becomes larger in relation to the frame. How can I set the zoom between `zoom = 2` and `zoom = 3`; A `zoom=2.5` for example.

```
leaflet(data) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      setView(lng=lng,lat=lat,zoom=2.5) %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(covariable),
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 0.3,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~(popup_covar),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 3,color = "#666",dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,bringToFront = FALSE))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862639/setting-the-zoom-level-to-7-25-in-shiny-leaflet-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting the zoom level to 7.25 in shiny leaflet r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862639/setting-the-zoom-level-to-7-25-in-shiny-leaflet-r)

Comment: Yes  @EliBerkow, it answers to my question